# Chrome not rendering HTML content?

Tags: html, web-development-server

for some reason my HTML is not rendering in chrome. For some reason, I am getting an odd webpage with just the IP Adress. I am not sure if it is something related to the server. Can anyone assist?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

VSCode starts the live-server in your project directory, and that's essentially what you're seeing in your browser.

Just move the HTML file into this directory (folder) and try running the server again, preferably your cursor clicked in the HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

Switch the name to index.html , that should help.